# Quectel EM05-CE Modem not detected after sleep

Tags: networking, network-manager, wwan

I've been using Quectel EM05-CE modem with my ThinkPad X1 Carbon 10th Gen , running Ubnutu 23.10 (mantic) for a year with no problem.

but after a clean install (to Ubuntu 23.10) today, the modem is fully working after clean boot like it was before, but when I close the lid and open it again, the LTE connection disappears from settings and ModemManager.

```
$ mmcli -L
no modems were found
```

These are the logs from ModemManager after clean boot...

```
Dec 15 00:54:10 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [cdc-wdm0/mbim] MBIM device is not QMI capable
Dec 15 00:54:10 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4] creating modem with plugin 'quectel' and '2' ports
Dec 15 00:54:10 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [base-manager] modem for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4' successfully created
Dec 15 00:54:10 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3': not supported by any plugin
Dec 15 00:54:10 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [modem0/cdc-wdm0/mbim] MBIM device is not QMI capable
Dec 15 00:54:11 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <warn>  [modem0] couldn't load carrier config: QMI PDC not supported

...

Dec 15 00:54:11 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [modem0] 3GPP registration state changed (unknown -> registering)
Dec 15 00:54:11 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [modem0] 3GPP registration state changed (registering -> home)
Dec 15 00:54:11 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [modem0] state changed (enabled -> registered)
```

and these are the logs from ModemManager after waking up from sleep.

```
Dec 15 01:02:36 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
Dec 15 01:02:38 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3': not supported by any plugin
Dec 15 01:03:27 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <info>  [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4] creating modem with plugin 'quectel' and '2' ports
Dec 15 01:03:27 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <warn>  [plugin/quectel] could not grab port cdc-wdm0: Cannot add port 'usbmisc/cdc-wdm0', unhandled port type
Dec 15 01:03:27 H2FCarbon30 ModemManager[1235]: <warn>  [base-manager] couldn't create modem for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4': Failed to find primary AT port
```

any solution or workaround? it worked with no problem before reinstalling Ubuntu.